# Undefined variable во view при создании переменной через middleware (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, view, middleware

Страница состоит из 2-х частей: "шапка" + "контент".

```
@include('layouts.header')
@yield('content')
```

В middleware определяется переменная $x, 100% получающая значение true или false и отправляется во вьюхи:

```
view()->share('x', $x);
```

Во вьюхе "content" всё работает, а в "header" на боевом сервере нет - **Undefined variable**!
При этом, на локальном сервере всё хорошо! Пробовал в ENV менять local на production и менял true/false на 1/0. Ничего не помогло.

Comment: Кеш сбрасывали?

Comment: Пробовал сбрасывать кеш, вьюхи и куки обнулять